# Google Colab: NotImplementedError: RarFile supports only mode=r

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create a separate .rar archive for each folder in my path. I'm using Google Colab to do this, but I'm getting this error back

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-544377e1db61> in <cell line: 8>()
      8 for folder in os.listdir(current_directory):
      9     # Create a RAR archive for each folder
---> 10     with rarfile.RarFile(folder + ".rar", "w") as archive:
     11         # Add all the files in the folder to the archive
     12         folder_path = os.path.join(current_directory, folder)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rarfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, charset, info_callback, crc_check, errors)
    685 
    686         if mode != "r":
--> 687             raise NotImplementedError("RarFile supports only mode=r")
    688 
    689         self._parse()

NotImplementedError: RarFile supports only mode=r
```

I am using this code

```
import os
import rarfile

# Get the current directory
current_directory = os.getcwd()

# Iterate over all the folders in the current directory
for folder in os.listdir(current_directory):
    # Create a RAR archive for each folder
    with rarfile.RarFile(folder + ".rar", "w") as archive:
        # Add all the files in the folder to the archive
        folder_path = os.path.join(current_directory, folder)
        for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
            archive.write(file_path, os.path.basename(file_path))

# Print a message to the user
print("All folders have been compressed into RAR archives.")
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that the "rarfile" library you're using in Google Colab only supports reading ("r") mode for RAR files, not writing ("w") mode. However, you can try using the "zipfile" library instead, which supports creating ZIP archives.

Here's an updated version of your code that creates separate ZIP archives for each folder in your path:

```
import os
import zipfile

# Get the current directory
current_directory = os.getcwd()

# Iterate over all the folders in the current directory
for folder in os.listdir(current_directory):
    # Create a ZIP archive for each folder
    with zipfile.ZipFile(folder + ".zip", "w") as archive:
        # Add all the files in the folder to the archive
        folder_path = os.path.join(current_directory, folder)
        for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
            archive.write(file_path, os.path.basename(file_path))

# Print a message to the user
print("All folders have been compressed into ZIP archives.")
```

This code uses the `zipfile` library to create ZIP archives instead of the `rarfile` library. It should work without any issues in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

According to [[ReadTheDocs.RARFile]: rarfile - RAR archive reader for Python](https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/#rarfile-rar-archive-reader-for-python) (**emphasis** is mine):

> This is Python module for [RAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_%28file_format%29) archive **reading**. The interface follows the style of [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html).

So you can't write *.rar* files (for now) using this module.

As an alternative, you could use other similar modules that do provide write capabilities like:

- [[Python.Docs]: zipfile - Work with ZIP archives](https://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) (mentioned above)
- [[Python.Docs]: tarfile - Read and write tar archive files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#module-tarfile)